# SQL: Prevent Duplicates in all EXCEPT specified column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have something of an odd question: I have two tables I wish to join with a Union. I don't want any duplicate columns, however each table has an extra variable I wrote into the SELECT clause specifying where they came from:

```
SELECT EOU.EventSessionKey, EOU.EventSourceID, EOU.EventSeq, 
    EOU.EventColumnName, EOU.ProSymbol,
    EOU.ProKey, tP.isActive, tP.Description, 
    'POSITIVE' AS ErrType FROM EOU
LEFT JOIN dbRunoff.dbo.tPro tP 
    ON tP.Symbol COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 
        = EOU.ProSymbol COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
WHERE tP.IsActive = 1 AND (EOU.ProKey IS NULL OR  EOU.ProKey <= 0)

UNION

SELECT EOU.EventSessionKey, EOU.EventSourceID, EOU.EventSeq, 
    EOU.EventColumnName, EOU.ProSymbol,
    EOU.ProKey, tP.isActive, tP.Description, 
    'DUPLICATE' AS ErrType FROM EOU
LEFT JOIN dbRunoff.dbo.tPro tP 
    ON tP.Symbol COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 
        = EOU.ProSymbol COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
JOIN ProFilter PF ON PF.ProKey = tp.ProKey
WHERE tP.IsActive = 1 AND (EOU.ProKey IS NULL OR  EOU.ProKey <= 0))
```

I am worried that the added text variable at the end will prevent the Union function from removing duplicate values properly. Is there any (simple/efficient) way of ensuring that union removes duplicate values between the tables but ignores the text variable which would otherwise cause the union to read no duplicates?

Note that I am looking for simple ways to do this. I know a few ways of brute forcing this, but efficiency and speed are concerns.

Comment: well, if it was a duplicate (only the last column was unique) which value would you want to attribute to that last column for the row you keep? Positive or Duplicate?

Comment: 'Duplicate', that name references a specific type of event I'm tracking so I'd want to catch that over 'Positive' which is a catch all for events.

Comment: Can duplicates appear in either subquery?  `union` removes duplicates both between and within its components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want the duplicate one, you can use `MIN()` with a `CTE`. `D` comes before `P` hence the join will use *Duplicate* when it exists over *Positive*.

Just a side note, I'm going to rewrite this without a `UNION`.

```
with cte as(
SELECT EOU.EventSessionKey, EOU.EventSourceID, EOU.EventSeq, 
    EOU.EventColumnName, EOU.ProSymbol,
    EOU.ProKey, tP.isActive, tP.Description, 
    'POSITIVE' AS ErrType FROM EOU
LEFT JOIN dbRunoff.dbo.tPro tP 
    ON tP.Symbol COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 
        = EOU.ProSymbol COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
WHERE tP.IsActive = 1 AND (EOU.ProKey IS NULL OR  EOU.ProKey <= 0)

UNION

SELECT EOU.EventSessionKey, EOU.EventSourceID, EOU.EventSeq, 
    EOU.EventColumnName, EOU.ProSymbol,
    EOU.ProKey, tP.isActive, tP.Description, 
    'DUPLICATE' AS ErrType FROM EOU
LEFT JOIN dbRunoff.dbo.tPro tP 
    ON tP.Symbol COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 
        = EOU.ProSymbol COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
JOIN ProFilter PF ON PF.ProKey = tp.ProKey
WHERE tP.IsActive = 1 AND (EOU.ProKey IS NULL OR  EOU.ProKey <= 0))

select distinct
    EventSessionKey
    ,EventSourceID
    ,EventSeq
    ,EventColumnName
    ,ProSymbol
    ,ProKey
    ,isActive
    ,Description
    ,min(cte2.ErrType)
from
    cte
    left join
    cte2 on cte.EventSessionKey = cte2.SessionKey --assumption based of column name. Use correct key to join.
group by
    EventSessionKey
    ,EventSourceID
    ,EventSeq
    ,EventColumnName
    ,ProSymbol
    ,ProKey
    ,isActive
    ,Description
```

**EDIT**

This should give you the same thing based off what I see in you query... basically i changed your `INNER JOIN` on `ProFilter` to a left join. If this join results to `TRUE` then it would have been a *Duplicate* record according to your `UNION`. If it wasn't there, it would be *Positive*

```
SELECT 
    EOU.EventSessionKey, 
    EOU.EventSourceID, 
    EOU.EventSeq, 
    EOU.EventColumnName, 
    EOU.ProSymbol,
    EOU.ProKey, 
    tP.isActive, 
    tP.Description, 
    case when pf.ProKey is null then 'Positive' else 'Duplicate' end as ErrType
FROM 
    EOU
LEFT JOIN 
    dbRunoff.dbo.tPro tP 
    ON tP.Symbol COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = EOU.ProSymbol COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
LEFT JOIN 
    ProFilter PF 
    ON PF.ProKey = tp.ProKey
WHERE 
    tP.IsActive = 1 
    AND (EOU.ProKey IS NULL OR  EOU.ProKey <= 0)
```

Comment: I agree @JohnCappelletti after I deconstructed the queries to tell the differences I saw why OP thought union was needed but it's one of the rarest things i use.

Comment: The LEFT JOIN logic is not the equivalent of the UNION query. You would have to start with a FULL OUTER JOIN, and compare every field for equality / nullity to actually simulate a simple UNION. See my answer below (soon).

Comment: I don't see why @LaughingVergil. The only difference in the two is a inner join in the second query `JOIN ProFilter PF ON PF.ProKey = tp.ProKey`. This would limit the second result set to a subset of the first query. Thus... changing this to a left join would fulfill the duplicate flag unless i'm overlooking something...

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` simply looks for missing rows in the second table. However, there is nothing in the definition of the problem that says that there cannot be rows in the second table that are not in the first table. Only a `FULL OUTER JOIN` will check for that. Additionally, a UNION looks for a difference in any field, not just the lack of a matching row. If the ProSymbol field differs between two rows matched by the EventSessionKey value, (say, 'A' and 'X'), there will be two rows returned.

Comment: Also, note that the UNION will only return one identical row, no matter how many may exist in the table (you are assuming only one row matching a given pattern exists in the table, which is not specified.)

Comment: But if they were in the second table and not the first they would t be a duplicate @LaughingVergil and I understand how union works. That's why I gave a way to use it with a CTE. However, based off the original question I do assume there would be only 2 versus many rows to make a duplicate.

Comment: Also I don't see how they could be in the second query and not the first. It's not a right join.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi Josh, i'm no expert, but I think you could try dumping the query into a derived table then selecting the min(ErrType) then group by the rest of column names.

```
select q.EventSessionKey, q.EventSourceID, q.EventSeq, q.EventColumnName, q.ProSymbol,
q.ProKey, q.isActive, q.Description, min(q.ErrType) as [ErrType] from
(
SELECT EOU.EventSessionKey, EOU.EventSourceID, EOU.EventSeq, 
EOU.EventColumnName, EOU.ProSymbol,
EOU.ProKey, tP.isActive, tP.Description, 
'POSITIVE' AS ErrType FROM EOU
LEFT JOIN dbRunoff.dbo.tPro tP 
ON tP.Symbol COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 
    = EOU.ProSymbol COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
WHERE tP.IsActive = 1 AND (EOU.ProKey IS NULL OR  EOU.ProKey <= 0)

UNION

SELECT EOU.EventSessionKey, EOU.EventSourceID, EOU.EventSeq, 
EOU.EventColumnName, EOU.ProSymbol,
EOU.ProKey, tP.isActive, tP.Description, 
'DUPLICATE' AS ErrType FROM EOU
LEFT JOIN dbRunoff.dbo.tPro tP 
ON tP.Symbol COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 
    = EOU.ProSymbol COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
JOIN ProFilter PF ON PF.ProKey = tp.ProKey
WHERE tP.IsActive = 1 AND (EOU.ProKey IS NULL OR  EOU.ProKey <= 0)) as q
```